# Google drive api Export-complete syntax

Tags: google-drive-api

Google drive api provides the following code to export files.  GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/export.  However, it doesn't work by itself, it needs the mimeType.  Where do I put the MimeType.  I need the complete syntax.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions are best accompanied by a [mcve] to show what you tried.

Comment: You may want to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) to know more about exporting Google Drive files and to know the supported export MIME types.

Comment: In addition to that, you may also practice in [try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export#response) to call `Files: export` method on live data to see the API request, response and to get the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$fileId/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document